# android findViewById returns null

Tags: android, null, android-linearlayout, findviewbyid

I have a problem finding a linear layout ... 
This is the xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:binding="http://www.gueei.com/android-binding/"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".controllers.ElencoInfrazioni" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Infrazione: " />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/elencoInfrazioni"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabellaDatiElencoInfrazioni"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:visibility="gone" > 

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Art. 3: " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/articolo3ElencoInfrazioni"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="non specificato"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panelArticolo4ElencoInfrazioni"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Art. 4: " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/articolo4ElencoInfrazioni"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="non specificato"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
        ....
```

The code that handles layout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.elenco_infrazioni);
    init();
}
private void init() {
    tabellaDati = (TableLayout) this
            .findViewById(R.id.tabellaDatiElencoInfrazioni);
    elencoInfrazioni = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.elencoInfrazioni);
    panelArticolo4 = (LinearLayout) this. 
            findViewById(R.id.panelArticolo4ElencoInfrazioni);
    articolo3 = (TextView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.articolo3ElencoInfrazioni);
    articolo4 = (TextView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.articolo4ElencoInfrazioni);
}
```

Every findViewById is ok except LinearLayout panelArticolo4 that gives me null...I need the linear layout to set its visibility..What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have more than one row in your table... are you using the same id for that LinearLayout for different rows?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all other views are ok? They won't give any error at initialization, until you try to use them. Could it be your view is not initialized at onCreate? If you are using fragments, you can try to initialize your views at onCreateView instead of onCreate.

Answer (score -4):

Don't use the word "this", everywhere,"this" in your init method refere to init and not your activity.

Comment: that makes no difference

Comment: try cleaning your project and rebuild. Your code seems to be right